# How to import my modules in other projects installed by PIP

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

How to import my modules `streaming_capture`, `streaming_information`, `report` in  in other project ?

I wrote a Python project called `long_term_streaming_info_capture`,

Then installed it in a new project under virtualenv environment.

If I want to import `StreamingCapture` I should called from `long_term_streaming_info_capture.scripts.streaming_capture import StreamingCapture`

Can I just use the `long_term_streaming_info_capture.streaming_capture` without the folder script in the import path ?

```
(develop+-)$ tree -L 3 -P "*.py"
.
├── helpers
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── animation
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── animation_helper.py
│       ├── dqa_file_io.py
│       ├── dqa_telnet.py
│       ├── file_io_helper.py
│       ├── shm_controller.py
│       ├── telnet_helper.py
│       ├── test_dqa_file_io.py
│       └── test_dqa_telnet.py
├── log
├── main.py
├── report.py
├── sandbox
├── streaming_capture.py
└── streaming_information.py
```

Project skeleton

```
.
├── HACKING.txt
├── MANIFEST.in
├── NEWS.txt
├── README.rst
├── bootstrap.py
├── buildout.cfg
├── setup.py
└── src
    ├── long_term_streaming_info_capture
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   ├── docs
    │   ├── scripts
    │   └── tests
    └── long_term_streaming_info_capture.egg-info
        ├── PKG-INFO
        ├── SOURCES.txt
        ├── dependency_links.txt
        ├── entry_points.txt
        ├── not-zip-safe
        └── top_level.txt
```

Here my setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import sys, os

here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
README = open(os.path.join(here, 'README.rst')).read()
NEWS = open(os.path.join(here, 'NEWS.txt')).read()


version = '0.1'

install_requires = [
    # List your project dependencies here.
    # For more details, see:
    # http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies
]


setup(name='long_term_streaming_info_capture',
    version=version,
    description="for capturing fps framerate",
    long_description=README + '\n\n' + NEWS,
    classifiers=[
      # Get strings from http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=list_classifiers
    ],
    keywords='',
    license='',
    packages=find_packages('src'),
    package_dir = {'': 'src'},include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
    install_requires=install_requires,
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts':
            ['long_term_streaming_info_capture=long_term_streaming_info_capture:main']
    }
)
```

Comment: For that first directory tree you show, where is that located? Is it inside the package? From the second tree it doesn't seem like the code you want to import is included in the package. You might also want to post your setup.py (especially what you have set for "packages").

Comment: Hi, I updated it. thanks :)

Comment: I see. What about my first question? Are those files inside the package somewhere? Since you named your package "src", what happens when you do "import src"?

Comment: @lost-theory I got ` from long_term_streaming_info_capture.src import *
ImportError: No module named src`

Comment: I found the solution, I should called from `long_term_streaming_info_capture.scripts.streaming_capture import StreamingCapture` But can I just use the long_term_streaming_info_capture.streaming_capture without the folder script in the import path ?

Comment: Yeah you should be able to move those files up one directory and get rid of the "scripts" module. Look at some packaging guides, I've used this one in the past: http://infinitemonkeycorps.net/docs/pph/. This one seems good too: http://guide.python-distribute.org/quickstart.html#lay-out-your-project Neither of them use a "src" or "scripts" directory, they're both flatter than the layout you've got.